# Where is exactly the place of Winterfell from Game of Thrones?

Tags: northern-ireland

How can I get to the filming location for Winterfell in Ireland, if I want to get there by car or public transport? I didn't find tickets for the tour when I'll stay in Ireland so I'm looking for alternative to see this castle from Game of Thrones.

Comment: "In Dublin/Belfast" sounds like a strange specification. The two cities are separated by about 150 km of countryside and an international (though quite open) border. [Also, answering the question in the title: In northern Westeros, on the Kingsroad about halfway between the Neck and the Wall. You can't miss it.]

Comment: You could have a look at [this](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Game_of_Thrones_tourism), they specify the locations for a lot of the sets.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Winterfell was actually filmed in two locations, Castle Ward in Northern Ireland for the majority of the filming, and Doune Castle in Scotland for the pilot episode.

It's only an hour's drive south east from Belfast. There aren't any other useful ways to get there other than the tours themselves.

[image]